# Minecraft Forge Method Data Type

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, minecraft-forge

I am trying to work with a MinecraftForge method in a Bukkit plugin.

Here is my code so far:

```
NetworkManager ic2 = new ic2.core.IC2().network;
DimensionManager dmm = new net.minecraftforge.common.DimensionManager();
T worlds = dmm.getWorlds(); // What Data Type?
```

The problem is that the `getWorlds()` method seems to be a data type of `in[]` which eclipse doesn't recognise, so now I am stuck because I have no idea what datatype to make the worlds variable.

This is the `getWorlds()` method in the version of Forge I am using

```
public static in[] getWorlds() {
     return (in[]) worlds.values().toArray(new in[worlds.size()]);
}
```

Did some further digging and found this in the forge version I am using.

```
import in;
```

and then there is an "`in`" class in the class list; But it doesn't appear in the list in eclipse; It's the same jar as the one I decompiled.

Comment: If you look at the [DimensionManager source code](https://github.com/Kiniamaro/MinecraftMod/blob/master/src/minecraft/net/minecraftforge/common/DimensionManager.java) you'll see that `DimensionManager#getWorlds` returns a `WorldServer[]`

Comment: So the data type should be "WorldServer"? that doesn't work either..

Comment: No, the data type should be `WorldServer[]`

Comment: Also tried that, still same result. "Type mismatch: cannot convert from in[] to WorldServer[]"

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct API?

Comment: I just decompiled the version of Forge i am using (i can't use the latest) and here is what it look like `public static in[] getWorlds()
  {
    return (in[])worlds.values().toArray(new in[worlds.size()]);
  }`

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the `getWorlds` in the Forge library returns `in[]` is because of Mojang's obfuscation. Forge cannot modify every single reference to `in` to `WorldServer` because that would be too complex.

Because most of the classes used in Minecraft are part of the default package, they cannot be imported directly.

Mods are able to get past this limitation because they use have a special modules that converts references in the output bytecode to refer the the obfuscated classes.

You will need to compile your code against Bukkit using the Forge compiler.